# plsql sum another table values to joined tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables.First table is student.Second is student_detail and last one special_codes.

```
student table
studentname | invoiceno |tax |invoiceamount
Paul          10         500   1950
Georghe       20         1000  6850
Mary          30         1500  1900
Messy         40         2000  7050

studentdetail
invoiceno   | code   | product | amount
10            101      pencil    100
10            102      rubber    350
10            103      bag       1500
20            108      wheel     5000
20            109      tv        1500
20            110      ps        300
20            111      mouse     50
30            103      bag       1500
30            105      keyboard  400
40            111      mouse     50
40            112      car       7000
```

I can join these two table like this and get result table

```
select s.studentname,s.tax,s.invoiceamount,st.product,sum(st.amount) from student s, studentdetail st
where s.invoiceno = st.invoiceno 
group by
s.studentname,
s.tax,
s.invoiceamount,
st.product

result table
studentname tax   invoiceamount product  amount
Paul        500   1950          bag      1500
Paul        500   1950          pencil   100
Paul        500   1950          rubber   350
Messy       2000  7050          car      7000
Messy       2000  7050          mouse    50
Mary        1500  1900          bag      1500
Mary        1500  1900          keyboard 400
Georghe     1000  6850          mouse    50
Georghe     1000  6850          ps       300
Georghe     1000  6850          tv       1500
Georghe     1000  6850          wheel    5000
```

Last table is special codes.It contains only one column which is called code

```
specialcodes table
code
101
102
113
104
105
110
111
```

What i want to do is to look up studentdetail table and to find codes that are same in specialcodes.Then to sum amount values and write sum to result table as another column.Result table
should be like that

```
result table(final)
studentname tax   invoiceamount product  amount taxexclude
Paul        500   1950          bag      1500   450
Paul        500   1950          pencil   100    450
Paul        500   1950          rubber   350    450
Messy       2000  7050          car      7000   50
Messy       2000  7050          mouse    50     50
Mary        1500  1900          bag      1500   400
Mary        1500  1900          keyboard 400    400
Georghe     1000  6850          mouse    50     350
Georghe     1000  6850          ps       300    350
Georghe     1000  6850          tv       1500   350
Georghe     1000  6850          wheel    5000   350
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use analytic functions rather than `GROUP BY` and aggregating:

```sql
select s.studentname,
       s.tax,
       invoiceamount,
       SUM(d.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY s.invoiceno) AS inv_amt_calc,
       d.product,
       d.amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.code IS NOT NULL THEN d.amount END)
         OVER (PARTITION BY s.invoiceno) AS taxexclude
from   student s
       INNER JOIN studentdetail d
       ON s.invoiceno = d.invoiceno 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN specialcodes c
       ON (c.code = d.code)
```

*Note: You can (and should) calculate the invoice amount from the `studentdetails` table rather than duplicating the data in the `student` table and violating Third-Normal Form.*

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | STUDENTNAME | TAX | INVOICEAMOUNT | INV_AMT_CALC | PRODUCT | AMOUNT | TAXEXCLUDE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Paul | 500 | 1950 | 1950 | rubber | 350 | 450 |
> | Paul | 500 | 1950 | 1950 | pencil | 100 | 450 |
> | Paul | 500 | 1950 | 1950 | bag | 1500 | 450 |
> | Georghe | 1000 | 6850 | 6850 | tv | 1500 | 350 |
> | Georghe | 1000 | 6850 | 6850 | wheel | 5000 | 350 |
> | Georghe | 1000 | 6850 | 6850 | ps | 300 | 350 |
> | Georghe | 1000 | 6850 | 6850 | mouse | 50 | 350 |
> | Mary | 1500 | 1900 | 1900 | bag | 1500 | 400 |
> | Mary | 1500 | 1900 | 1900 | keyboard | 400 | 400 |
> | Messy | 2000 | 7050 | 7050 | mouse | 50 | 50 |
> | Messy | 2000 | 7050 | 7050 | car | 7000 | 50 |

---

If you really want a version using `GROUP BY` then:

```sql
SELECT s.studentname,
       s.tax,
       s.invoiceamount,
       SUM(d.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY s.invoiceno) AS inv_amt_calc,
       d.product,
       d.amount,
       t.taxexclude
FROM   student s
       INNER JOIN studentdetail d
       ON s.invoiceno = d.invoiceno
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT invoiceno,
                SUM(amount) AS taxexclude
         FROM   studentdetail
         WHERE  code IN (SELECT code FROM specialcodes)
         GROUP BY
                invoiceno
       ) t
       ON s.invoiceno = t.invoiceno;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c9d4bdd7cb5cfdf799be95f606221feb)*

Comment: Thank you very much.It is working but i have to use group by :(

Comment: @tom Updated with a version using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Is it possible solve this problem without inner join and left outer join?With where conditions  can we solve the problem ?

Comment: @tom The query you wrote in the question has an `INNER JOIN`; you just used the legacy syntax using commas rather than the more modern ANSI-standard syntax. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=63c91fee2516b536b12c5e7404996f1c) So while you can write it with the joins in a `WHERE` clause, don't; use the more modern join syntax.